# gradle apply plugin conditionally in sub-modules w/o affecting root?

Tags: plugins, gradle

I am tinkering with this concept of a 'local.gradle' that can add/extend a build.gradle for a sub-project if the local.gradle exists.  Simple example:

```
if(file('local.gradle').exists()){
    apply from: 'local.gradle' 
}
```

This works ok, and can embellish local builds but not 'clog' up our continous builds with goop from workstations etc.

Trouble is, one of my local.gradle files wants to use a plugin like so:

```
apply plugin: 'fladoodle'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/niftystuff/pseudorepo'
        }
    }   
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.home:gradle-fladoodle-plugin:0.1'
    }
}
```

This kinda works, but then tasks and stuff in local.gradle don't really 'know' about stuff the multi-project build and root build file; stuff like tasks.getByPath(':somesub:somejar') doesn't seem to make sense in the local.gradle.

So I moved the buildscript stuff for locating the plugin to the root; near (actually in) the section in the root build where other plugin dependencies are declared.   The local.gradle just has an apply and then gradle stuff for that plugin; all is well and that absolute path stuff seems to be working now.   I have not included any reference to local.gradle in the root setting.gradle ...nor do I want too...

But, now I have stuff in root build.gradle that really doesn't belong there -- as the root will never know if a sub will have a local.gradle.     NOTE:   the buildscript stuff is NOT in allprojects{  } or subprojects  {}   -- so it really can't ask the question for the current sub that I am processing, is there a local.gradle; if so add a new maven repo to the buildscript { } for resolution of a plugin that maybe used in the local.gradle  (further, the root should really NOT need to know if a local file wishes to apply additional pluggins -- just smells like bad coupling).

***So can a conditionally included 'local.gradle' file some how affect the plugin "apply from" dependencies in a way w/o having to leak this information into other places (i.e. the root) of a build?***

Comment: If I understand right
1. You want to apply `local.gradle` conditionally.
2. The local.gradle applies a custom plugin available in some repository. You want both dependency definition for plugin and `apply plugin` statement within `local.gradle`

Correct ?

Comment: Yes.   You got that just about right.  When I had the deps for the plugin in the local.gradle; some things were not quite right:  gradle ABS paths didn't seem to resolve.   moving the deps to the root -- made it behave -- but kinda defeats the idea of local.gradle      maybe I am barking up tree..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `buildscript{}` applies only for the root project in a multi-project gradle build.
2. This means the dependency of your custom plugin can only be added to root project's `buildscript{}` block;
   You can try below approach of separating your plugin's dependency from common `buildscript{}` configuration

### Root project's `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    // Other buildscript configurations

    apply from : 'local-buildscript.gradle'
}
subproject {
    if(file('local.gradle').exists()){
         apply from: 'local.gradle' 
    }
}
// Other code of build.gradle
```

### `local-buildscript.gradle` in Root project directory

```
project.buildscript {   // NOTE it is project.buildscript
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/niftystuff/pseudorepo'
        }
    }   
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.home:gradle-fladoodle-plugin:0.1'
    }
}
```

NOTE here that you still are not moving the configuration into `local.gradle`, but you are creating your own gradle file for `buildscript{}` which you can maintain.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Took a while to get back to this -- but your suggestions seems to work for me.   The only tweak was I did add  if(file('local-buildscript.gradle').exists()){ apply from:  'local-buildscript.gradle' }   inside my root's buildscript { } block.   The local-buildscript.gradle had basically what you documented above.        THANKS!